# How to start xampp using sudo xampp command?

Tags: command-line, xampp

For starting xampp i need to run below command.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start
```

**Problem is:**

I don't like to write `/opt/lampp/xampp`

**Need Solution like:**

```
sudo xampp start
```

- want only `xampp` command instead of `/opt/lampp/xampp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please Use any single method, Both Methods are working correctly.**

> Method 1 : create symlink

You need to create `xampp`'s symlink which will call `/opt/lampp/xampp`. To do that, run:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/xampp /usr/local/bin
```

- This command will create `xampp`'s symlink in `/usr/local/bin` folder.
- Now terminal would be able to **recognise** `xampp` command as `/opt/lampp/xampp`.
- You can run `sudo xampp` command now. :)

---

> Method 2 : add command in shell file.

You need to create `xampp`'s alias which will call `/opt/lampp/xampp`. To do that,

***note :** you can check your default shell using `echo $SHELL` command.*

**condition 1 : bash shell**

```
nano .bashrc
```

add below line in bottom of .bashrc.

```
# Custom alias
alias xampp='sudo /opt/lampp/xampp'
```

[image]

- then save it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>
- now run below command :

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

- You can run `sudo xampp` command now. :)

**condition 2 : zsh shell**

```
nano .zshrc
```

add below line in bottom of .zshrc.

```
# Custom alias
alias xampp='sudo /opt/lampp/xampp'
```

[image]

- then save it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>
- now run below command :

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

- You can run `sudo xampp` command now. :)

> Output after using any of single method.

[image: xampp status]

Comment: The `/usr/bin` folder is controlled by APT. So for better maintenance you have to use `/usr/local` folder with `sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/xampp /usr/local/bin` .

Comment: @N0rbert It really help me. and you are right.